# Changing attribute with DOM in PHP does not save correctly

Tags: php, dom, setattribute

I have a weird bug involving the DOM. I am trying to iterate over every href inside the document and replace it with an absolute path if necessary. The problem is, after I use `$dom->setttribute()`, `getAttribute` returns the changed value. Yet, if I `saveHTML()` or query tags again using getElementsByTagName and getAttribute, the values have got truncated from http://example.com/path.php?ccc to http://example.com.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
//include 'url_to_absolute.php';


function url_to_absolute($url, $href) {
    return trim($url . $href);
}

 $url = 'http://example.com';
 //$url = $_GET["url"];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
@curl_close();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($contents);


//change the urls to absolute
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $anchor)
{
    $href = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
    $abs = url_to_absolute($url, $href);
    $anchor->removeAttribute('href');
    $anchor->setAttribute('href', $abs);

    //changed
    $newhref = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
    echo "newhref = " . $newhref; //shows http://example.com/.... (good)
}


$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $anchor)
{
    echo "new2 = " . $anchor->getAttribute('href'); //returns http://example.com only
}

//print output
echo @$dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

Comment: Could you post your url_to_absolute() function please?  And, in your snippet, the $url variable doesn't exist.

Comment: My url_to_absolute function I got from here: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/05/php_tip_how_convert_relative_url_absolute_url#Code

Comment: my $url variable was set earlier as $url = $_GET['url']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these curl options + curl_init($url):

```
<?php
//include 'url_to_absolute.php';
function url_to_absolute($url, $href){
    return trim($url . $href);
}

$url = 'http://example.com';
//$url = $_GET["url"];
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($contents);
//$dom->saveHTMLFile('dom_doc_test.html');


//change the urls to absolute
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $anchor)
{
    $href = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
    $abs = url_to_absolute($url, $href);
    $anchor->removeAttribute('href');
    $anchor->setAttribute('href', $abs);

    //changed
    $newhref = $anchor->getAttribute('href') . '<br />';
    echo "newhref = " . $newhref; //shows http://example.com/.... (good)
}

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $anchor)
{
    echo "new2 = " . $anchor->getAttribute('href') . '<br />'; //returns http://example.com only
}

//print output
echo @$dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be a bug in your url_to_absolute function. My simple url_to_absolute is:

```
function url_to_absolute($url, $href){
    return trim($url . $href);
}

$url = 'http://example.com';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<html><body><a href="/path.html?q=hello&a=bye"></a><a href="/path2.html?before=34&after=44"></a></body></html>');

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $anchor){
    $href = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
    echo "href = " . $href . '<br />';
}

echo '<br />';

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $anchor){
    $href = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
    $abs = url_to_absolute($url, $href);
    $anchor->removeAttribute('href');
    $anchor->setAttribute('href', $abs);  

    $newhref = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
    echo "newhref = " . $newhref . '<br />';
}

echo '<br />';

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $anchor){
    echo "new2 = " . $anchor->getAttribute('href') . '<br />';
}
```

and the result is:

```
href = /path.html?q=hello&a=bye
href = /path2.html?before=34&after=44

newhref = http://example.com/path.html?q=hello&a=bye
newhref = http://example.com/path2.html?before=34&after=44

new2 = http://example.com/path.html?q=hello&a=bye
new2 = http://example.com/path2.html?before=34&after=44
```

Comment: I replaced my code with your simple url_to_absolute function.  I am still getting the same problem.  I edited my snippet to show how my code looks now